# Mobx State Tree: Create instance on the fly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react, mobx-state-tree

I have a model named Event, which has a property referencing to another model.
I create the Event instances on the fly, without connecting them to a root store. 
The problem is that mst cannot resolve the reference (I guess because they are not on the same tree)

What is the correct way to create models with references on the fly? I don't need to hold them for shared state.

Here's a reproduction sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/004n1kx5zp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use **get** function like here https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-state-tree#customizable-references